# Validate emails in array using foreach

Tags: php, wp-mail

How do I validate an array of emails from a textbox before sending them to the `wp_mail()` function?

```
$emails = 'test@test.com;test2@test2.com
email3@email3.com,email4@email4.com, email5.com';

$emails = preg_split('/[;,\n]/', $emails);
$validEmails = array();
$subject = 'Hey Subject';
$message = 'I am a message';

foreach($emails as $key=>$value){
  if (is_email($value)) {
    array_push($validEmails, $value);
  }
}

wp_mail($validEmails, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The sample code above stops on the `if (is_email())` condition. How can I validate each email in the array whichever way before sending to the mail function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware you can pass a comma-separated string of email adresses to `wp_mail`?

```
// Make sure your email strings only uses comma as a separator
$emails = preg_replace('~[,;\s]+~', ',', $emails);
```

Then just throw that string into `wp_mail`’s first argument. Depending on exactly what you want to do with the emails, this approach may be sufficient.

The `wp_mail` function internally relies on the PHPMailer library (unless you use a redefined `wp_mail` function). PHPMailer validates the email before adding it to the recipient list. Invalid emails will be skipped.

Comment: I was aware that you could use comma-seperated string but because i was using explode function to get emails from text box, i was running into the problems mentioned above. Thanks very much, much appreciated Geert.